# Construct html column matching classes

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have buit a table in html like this:

[image]

The idea would be, that I type manually a number in "initial". Column 2 should display the double of that value. Column 3 should display the triple. Column 4 should display 4 times the value. Column 5 should display 5 times the value. And "Sum" should display the sum of Double + Triple + Fourth + Fifth.

I am not sure how I have to combine the classes in the script below (I guess through "GetElementbyClass") so that I could have the results. Please note that the table will be not only 2 rows but more than 10. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```css
table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<! --COMIENZO TABLA -->
<table id="MyTable" class="egt">

  <! --PRIMERA LINEA -->
  <tr>    
      <th>Initial</th>
      <th>Double</th>
      <th>Triple</th>
      <th>Fourth</th>
      <th>Fifth</th>
      <th>Sum</th>
  </tr>

  <! --SEGUNDA LINEA -->   
  <tr> 
     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel"> 
     </td>  

     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel2" >
     </td>   


     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel3" >
     </td>   

     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel4" >
     </td>   

      <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel5" >
     </td>  

      <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel6" >
     </td>
  </tr>

  <! --TERCERA LINEA -->  
  <tr> 
     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel"> 
     </td>  

     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel2" >
     </td>   


     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel3" >
     </td> 

     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel4" >
     </td> 

     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel5" >
     </td> 

      <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel6" >
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
var fuel = document.getElementsByClassName ("fuel");
var fuel2 = document.getElementsByClassName ("fuel2");
var fuel3 = document.getElementsByClassName ("fuel3");
var fuel4 = document.getElementsByClassName ("fuel4");
var fuel5 = document.getElementsByClassName ("fuel5");
  
  
function calculate() {
    fuel2.value = Number(fuel.value) * 2;
    fuel3.value = Number(fuel.value) * 3;
    fuel4.value = Number(fuel.value) * 4;
    fuel5.value = Number(fuel.value) * 5;
    fuel6.value = fuel2.value + fuel3.value + fuel4.value + fuel5.value;
}

var inputElement = document.getElementByClassName('fuel');
inputElement.addEventListener('change', calculate);
var inputElement = document.getElementByClassName('fuel2');
inputElement.addEventListener('change', calculate);
var inputElement = document.getElementByClassName('fuel3');
inputElement.addEventListener('change', calculate);
var inputElement = document.getElementByClassName('fuel4');
inputElement.addEventListener('change', calculate);
var inputElement = document.getElementByClassName('fuel5');
inputElement.addEventListener('change', calculate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var Initial = document.querySelectorAll('.fuel')
var Double = document.querySelectorAll('.fuel2')
var Triple = document.querySelectorAll('.fuel3')
var Fourth = document.querySelectorAll('.fuel4')
var Fifth = document.querySelectorAll('.fuel5')
var Sum = document.querySelectorAll('.fuel6')


Initial.forEach(myFunction);
function myFunction(item, index) {
  item.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  var initialValue = event.target.value;
  Double[index].value = initialValue*2;
  Triple[index].value = initialValue*3;
  Fourth[index].value = initialValue*4;
  Fifth[index].value = initialValue*5;
  Sum[index].value = initialValue*14;
});
}
```

```css
table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<! --COMIENZO TABLA -->
<table id="MyTable" class="egt">

  <! --PRIMERA LINEA -->
  <tr>    
      <th>Initial</th>
      <th>Double</th>
      <th>Triple</th>
      <th>Fourth</th>
      <th>Fifth</th>
      <th>Sum</th>
  </tr>

  <! --SEGUNDA LINEA -->   
  <tr> 
     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel"> 
     </td>  

     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel2" >
     </td>   


     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel3" >
     </td>   

     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel4" >
     </td>   

      <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel5" >
     </td>  

      <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel6" >
     </td>
  </tr>

  <! --TERCERA LINEA -->  
  <tr> 
     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel"> 
     </td>  

     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel2" >
     </td>   


     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel3" >
     </td> 

     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel4" >
     </td> 

     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel5" >
     </td> 

      <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel6" >
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would do it like this.

First Step
Select all the classes of each field using querySelectorAll. We know querySelectorAll returns an array so lets add a forEach loop to the "Initial" array.

Second Step
Now add 'change' Event Listener to each item of "Initial" array.

Third Step
Store the value from 'Initial' input and then use it to modify Double,Triple,Fourth,Fifth inputs values and use it for the calculation of sum.

Comment: Nice solution, but please try explaining what you've done. And also why you did it, so the OP can learn from it. Instead of just copying code.

Comment: just ```Sum[index].value = initialValue*14;``` since he said sum should display from double to fifth

Comment: My bad. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using document.getElementsByClassName. This method will return a collection of matched DOM elements. Even if there is only one matching element (one element with the class fuel for example).

So this means, that you need to select the first element in de result list.

Try doing it like this:

`var fuel = document.getElementsByClassName("fuel")[0];`

Also later on, you are using the method `getElementByClassName`, which does not exist. It's always getElementsByClassName (plural). And it always returns a collection of matched elements. Even if it may be an empty collection.

---

More info on getElementsByClassName:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

---

Also, your are defining the same element multiple times. For example, the first line in your code: `var fuel = document.getElementsByClassName ("fuel");`.

And later on you define: `var inputElement = document.getElementByClassName('fuel');`.

Both these statements should append [0] on the end, to select the input.
But even more so, you could reduce this to one statement. Because both variables point to exactly the same element. You could reduce your code by almost half, just remove the duplicate variables.

Answer (score 0):

All explaination are provided in comments inside code

```
<table id="MyTable" class="egt" border="2px solid black">
        <!-- Use thead and tbody your Code will run without them but it is good practice to use them -->
        <thead>
            <tr>    
                <th>Initial</th><th>Double</th><th>Triple</th><th>Fourth</th><th>Fifth</th>
                <th>Sum</th>
            </tr> 
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr> 
                <!-- the function calculate1() will automatically called when ever values changed in the input field -->
                <td><input type="number" onchange="calculate1()" class="fuel"> </td> 
                 <!--instead of using input tag i use label because we dont have to enter any value here we just want to insert value based on above input -->
                <td><label class="fuel" ></td>  
                 <td><label class="fuel" ></td> 
                 <td><label class="fuel" ></td> 
                 <td><label class="fuel" ></td> 
                 <td><label class="fuel" ></td>
             </tr> 
             <tr> 
                 <td><input type="number" onchange="calculate2()" class="fuel2"> </td>  
                <td><label class="fuel2" ></td>   
                <td><label class="fuel2" ></td> 
                <td><label class="fuel2" ></td> 
                <td><label class="fuel2" ></td> 
                <td><label class="fuel2" ></td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <script>
            function calculate1(){
                // as fuel is used as a class name for more than one tag so the var fuel will form array of all elements that has fuel class name
                var fuel = document.getElementsByClassName("fuel")
                // as fuel is array and the input value is also located at first position so we will use fuel[0].value to get value that user inserted
                let val1=parseInt(fuel[0].value)
                let sum1=0
                // As the loop is used here to insert values in label so we start loop from 1 because position 0 is used to get user value  
                //fuel.length gives length of array and we use fuel.length -1 because we have to reserve last position in array for sum 
                for(let i=1; i<(fuel.length-1); i++){
                    fuel[i].textContent = val1*(i+1) 
                    sum1+=val1*(i+1)
                }
                fuel[fuel.length-1].textContent = sum1
            }
            function calculate2(){
                var fuel2 = document.getElementsByClassName ("fuel2");
                let val2=parseInt(fuel2[0].value)
                let sum2=0
                for(let i=1; i<(fuel2.length-1); i++){
                    fuel2[i].textContent = val2*(i+1)
                    sum2+=val2*(i+1)
                }
                fuel2[fuel2.length-1].textContent = sum2
            }
      </script>
```